# dsPIC: Reading timer registers and get wrong value

Tags: c, timer, firmware, dspic

On a [dsPIC33CK512MP608](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/dsPIC33CK512MP608) I set up SCCP1 Timer so it increments every 1 us.
My goal is to mimic the [millis()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/) function of Arduino. I'm aware it's not a super-precise way to measure time, but it's accurate enough for non-critical delays. I'm using [XC16](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/develop/mplab-xc-compilers/downloads-documentation#XC16) v2.10 GCC compiler, MPLAB X IDE v6.05 with all the packs updated.

Here my code:

```
uint32_t tick100ms = 0;

uint32_t millis(void)
{
    // clock source 1 MHz
    return TimerBase1us_CounterGet() / 1000;
}

int main(void)
{
    // initialization stuff

    // main loop
    for (;;)
    {
        uint32_t timestamp = millis();
        if (timestamp - tick100ms > 100)
        {
            printf("%ld\t%lu\t%lu\r\n", timestamp - tick100ms, timestamp, tick100ms);
            tick100ms = timestamp;
        }
     }
}
```

Here the implementation of the `SCCP1_Timer_CounterGet()` function (by Microchip):

```
inline static uint32_t SCCP1_Timer_CounterGet(void)
{
    if(CCP1CON1Lbits.T32 == 1)
    {
        return (((uint32_t)CCP1TMRH << 16U) | CCP1TMRL);
    }
    else
    {
        return (uint32_t)CCP1TMRL;
    }
}
```

And here the settings of the timer:

```
void SCCP1_Timer_Initialize(void)
{
    // MOD ; CCSEL disabled; TMR32 32 Bit; TMRPS 1:1; CLKSEL REFO; TMRSYNC disabled; CCPSLP disabled; CCPSIDL disabled; CCPON disabled; 
    CCP1CON1L = 0x120; //The module is disabled, till other settings are configured
    //SYNC None; ALTSYNC disabled; ONESHOT disabled; TRIGEN disabled; IOPS Each Time Base Period Match; RTRGEN disabled; OPSRC Timer Interrupt Event; 
    CCP1CON1H = 0x0;
    //ASDG 0x0; SSDG disabled; ASDGM disabled; PWMRSEN disabled; 
    CCP1CON2L = 0x0;
    //ICSEL ; AUXOUT Disabled; ICGSM Level-Sensitive mode; OCAEN disabled; OENSYNC disabled; 
    CCP1CON2H = 0x0;
    //PSSACE Tri-state; POLACE disabled; OSCNT None; OETRIG disabled; 
    CCP1CON3H = 0x0;
    //ICOV disabled; ICDIS disabled; SCEVT disabled; ASEVT disabled; TRCLR disabled; TRSET disabled; ICGARM disabled; 
    CCP1STATL = 0x0;
    //TMRL 0x0000; 
    CCP1TMRL = 0x0;
    //TMRH 0x0000; 
    CCP1TMRH = 0x0;
    //PRL 65535; 
    CCP1PRL = 0xFFFF;
    //PRH 65535; 
    CCP1PRH = 0x98;
    //CMPA 0; 
    CCP1RA = 0x0;
    //CMPB 0; 
    CCP1RB = 0x0;
    //BUFL 0x0000; 
    CCP1BUFL = 0x0;
    //BUFH 0x0000; 
    CCP1BUFH = 0x0;
    
    SCCP1_Timer_TimeoutCallbackRegister(&SCCP1_TimeoutCallback);
    CCP1CON1Lbits.CCPON = 1; //Enable Module
}
```

I read [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/12588/54202) answer about the handling of the rollover and I should do the math correctly (i.e. compare the subtraction).
Here a real output of the code above:

```
...
101 15207 15106
101 15308 15207
101 15409 15308
101 15510 15409
-44 15466 15510
101 15567 15466
101 15668 15567
101 15769 15668
101 15870 15769
...
```

I'm pretty sure the timer *cannot* go backwards... hence there is something wrong in the code. I think there are two options: my code and the Microchip code (`SCCP1_Timer_CounterGet()`).

Do you see any evidence of errors in either snippets that could lead to that weird behavior?

### UPDATE

I tried to replace my `millis()` function as follow:

```
uint32_t millis()
{
    return (((uint32_t)CCP1TMRH << 16U) | CCP1TMRL) / 1000;
}
```

to avoid any overhead but the behavior is the same.
I also commented all the other stuff (but the UART1 of course) in my project, leaving just the code above, but again nothing has changed.

### UPDATE 2

Here the disassembled code of the `millis()` function:

```
!uint32_t millis()
!{
0x868A: LNK #0x0
!    return (((uint32_t)CCP1TMRH << 16U) | CCP1TMRL) / 1000;
0x868C: MOV CCP1TMRH, W0
0x868E: CLR W1
0x8690: SL W0, #0, W3
0x8692: MOV #0x0, W2
0x8694: MOV CCP1TMRL, W0
0x8696: CLR W1
0x8698: IOR W2, W0, W0
0x869A: IOR W3, W1, W1
0x869C: MOV #0x3E8, W2
0x869E: MOV #0x0, W3
0x86A0: RCALL ___udivsi3
!}
0x86A2: ULNK
0x86A4: RETURN
```

As far as I understand is not *inline*.
The call stack (execution path?) seems always the same:

```
main.c line 54 (breakpoint inside millis())
main.c line 126 (call of millis())
```

To check the call stack when the wrong value is read, I modified the function as follow:

```
uint32_t millis()
{
    static uint32_t old = 0;
    uint32_t value = (((uint32_t)CCP1TMRH << 16U) | CCP1TMRL) / 1000;
    
    if (value < old)
    {
        int foo = 0;
        foo++; // <-- breakpoint here
    }
    
    old = value;
    return value;
}
```

When the breakpoint fires, the call stack is always the same.

### UPDATE 3

Sorry for many updates, but I'm digging deeper.

```
uint32_t millis()
{
    static uint32_t old = 0;
    uint32_t h = CCP1TMRH;
    uint32_t l = CCP1TMRL;
            
    uint32_t value = (((uint32_t) h << 16U) | l) / 1000;
    if (value < old)
    {
        int foo = 0;
        foo++;
    }
    
    old = value;
    return value;
}
```

Here I'm able to inspect the register values when the issue happens.
Well, `CCP1TMRL` is always 5 and the math is wrong:

```
CCP1TMRH = 92
CCP1TMRL = 5
```

`value` should be: (92 << 16 + 5) / 1000 = **6029**
But the debugger says `value` is **5936**!!!

[image]

Removing the `/ 1000` I discovered that when it happens the real value differs by 2^16:

```
CCP1TMRH = 50
CCP1TMRL = 0
```

`value` should be 3276800, debugger shows 3211264. Difference is 65536

```
CCP1TMRH = 152
CCP1TMRL = 0
```

`value` should be 9961472, debugger shows 9895936. Difference is 65536

Comment: Which execution path in SCCP1_Timer_CounterGet() does it take? Always the same? Does your compiler inline the function? Are you executing anything else in the background? Which compiler are you using, a real C compiler or some MPLAB spawn?

Comment: @Lundin I'm using Microchip GCC xc16 v2.00 compiler; the project has other functions but none uses SCCP1; not sure how to check the "execution path" and if my compiler inlines the function.

Comment: @Lundin tried also v2.10 just released

Comment: What does you mean "Microchip GCC xc16"? GCC and MPLAB XC are different compilers, yes? Also does that mean that this is 16 bit MCU or is it 32 bit?

Comment: "not sure how to check the "execution path"" Breakpoints in a debugger.  "if my compiler inlines the function" Check the disassembly. Both of these things are basic tools that you need to learn how to use as a programmer.

Comment: @Lundin [release notes](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/DEV/ProductDocuments/SoftwareTools/Readme_XC16.html) talks about `gcc`. The executable is `xc16-gcc`. Of course is a proprietary variant. Sorry if I used the wrong words.

Comment: @Lundin the MPU is a 16-bit one, as you can see from the datasheet I linked.

Comment: @Lundin, ok I'm going to find out how to inspect the disassembled code to understand if it inlined the function. Anyway, please look at the latest update. It exhibits the same behavior even without the `inline` function.

Comment: @Lundin question updated with the last details you asked

Comment: "I'm pretty sure the timer cannot go backwards..." - Just a comment here that on the dsPICs some of the Counters/Timers do indeed go backwards.  They count from a value back to 0 upon which an Interrupt can be fired.  Not saying this is happening here, but just be aware that yes, some can count backwards.

Comment: @Mark, right. I should have said: "not with the configuration I've shown"

Comment: @Mike That feature is sometimes referred to as "modulus down counter" and is separate from free running timers/output compare - you can't have both at once.

Comment: Anyways, I'd be inclined to yell "compiler bug" or "silicon bug" at this. MPLAB has a historical nasty reputation as a piece of non-conforming junk, while gcc does not. That is, unless it's a classic stack overflow corrupting your stack. Check the SP at the point where you get the incorrect behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a pretty standard race condition. Consider the scenario, in which by the time of first reading the timer register holds `91:65535`.

After

```
 uint32_t h = CCP1TMRH;
```

`h` is `91`. Meanwhile, the timer keeps running, and the lower half overflows. The register is `92:0`, and after

```
 uint32_t l = CCP1TMRL;
```

`l` is 0. You are 65536 ticks in the past.

A typical way to deal with it is to read lower half twice:

```
uint32_t l_0 = CCP1TMRL;
/* A */
uint32_t h = CCP1TMRH;
/* B */
uint32_t l_1 = CCP1TMRL;

// If l1 > l0, there was no overflow. You may trust both h and l_1.
// Otherwise,

if (l1 < l_0) {
    // There was an overflow. It could've happen at point A, or point B.
    // You cannot trust h, so re-read it
    h = CCP1TMRH;
}

// Now ` and l_2 are good, no matter how we arrived here.
return (((uint32_t) h << 16U) | l) / 1000;
```

Comment: It makes sense and it works! Out of curiosity, since it is a "pretty standard race condition", why Microchip released such a buggy code? I mean, if the hardware does not allow to read a pair of registers together, the original code is simply wrong, isn'it?

Comment: I wouldn't call it buggy. It is a 16 bit chip, and it cannot read 32 bits in a single bus cycle.  As a side note, it is not just PIC. I have seen people (including myself) bitten by the same problem on a wide varieties of architectures, from 8 to 32 bits. I can imagine few ways to fix it in hardware, but I don't like any of them (I am not a chip designer though). An application note could be helpful; OTOH it is already a common knowledge.

Comment: Got it. I used AVRs and they are 8-bit MCUs, IIRC they can read a 16-bit timer registers (two 8-bit registers) without this problem. Hence I was not aware about this. I learned something new!